# ios change background image dependant on device

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I'm trying to set up my app so that on an iPhone4s, a different background image is displayed, but the code below produces a black background. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you

```
    UIImageView *bgImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame: self.view.bounds];

if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad){
    bgImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"background_rest-ipad.png"];
}

else if ( [GUIHelper isPhone5] ) {
    bgImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"info-screen-bg@2x.png"];
}
else {
    bgImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"info-screen-bg-i4s.png"];
}

bgImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
bgImageView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
[self.view addSubview: bgImageView];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Asset Catalog and it will manage your images based on device...

Thought, with your code, make sure the names of the image files are correct and the files itself are present.